# Ошибка при задании начальных центроидов в K-means

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy, cluster, кластеризация

Коллеги, помогите исправить ошибку в коде.

Не могу задать случайные центроиды для дальнейшей кластеризации K-means.

```
    # Number of clusters
k = 3
# X coordinates of random centroids
C_x = np.random.randint(0, np.max(X)-20, size=k)
# Y coordinates of random centroids
C_y = np.random.randint(0, np.max(X)-20, size=k)
C = np.array(list(zip(C_x, C_y)), dtype=np.float32)
print(C)
```

возникает ошибка

> ValueError: high is out of bounds for int32

Был бы признателен если поможете новичку в ML

Comment: Вы хотите написать свою реализацию `k-means`?

Comment: пытаюсь свой датасет прикрутить на пример данный в этом блогеhttps://mubaris.com/posts/kmeans-clustering/.....А так да, в идеале свою реализацию сделать, но пока я новичок в этом

Comment: а почему не хотите использовать готовые реализации `k-means` (например из SciKit-Learn), где начальные центроиды выбираются по алгоритму `k-means++`?

Comment: если подскажите где взять/почитать и применить буду премного благодарен!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно в векторе `X` максимальное значение выходит за пределы `np.int32`:

```
In [73]: np.iinfo('int32')
Out[73]: iinfo(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, dtype=int32)
```

как следствие, существует вероятность того, что `np.random.randint(..., np.max(X)-20, ...)` вернёт число выпадающее за границы диапазона, например:

```
In [76]: np.random.randint(0, 10**10)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: high is out of bounds for int32
```

чтобы исправить эту ошибку можно явно задать тип данных:

```
In [77]: np.random.randint(0, 10**10, dtype='int64')
Out[77]: 7882851664
```

---

Но главные трудности вас ждут впереди - `k-means` может сходиться в **локальных** минимумах, что сильно зависит от выбора начальных центроидов. Поэтому все промышленные реализации данного алгоритма делают несколько вычислений с различными начальными центроидами, в итоге возвращается лучший результат. В `SciKit-Learn` используется алгоритм `k-means++` для выбора начальных центроидов, суть которого в выборе центроидов как можно дальше удаленных друг от друга.

PS [ссылка на теоритическую часть документации](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means)

Пример использования ([из документации](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)):

```
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
>>> kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
>>> kmeans.labels_
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
>>> kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [4, 4]])
array([0, 1], dtype=int32)
>>> kmeans.cluster_centers_
array([[1., 2.],
       [4., 2.]])
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, как всегда ваши развернутые ответы очень полезны!!!!